# Name of a 50's/60's B-movie where people are trapped in a supermarket with tentacled monsters in the fog outside.

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

It wasn't Stephen King's "The Mist" but I believe it inspired his story.  I saw it as a kid in the late 70's on the Saturday afternoon "Creature Feature" show.

Comment: pretty sure if you saw it in the 70s then it actually inspired the mist and not the other way around but unfortunately its not referenced on the wiki under influences

Comment: the only other TV show that came to mind was 5 students trapped in a high school they cannot escape from: [Abduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abduction_%28The_Outer_Limits%29) from The Outer Limits, but the alien wasn't tentacled

Comment: B-Movie means?.

Comment: @rps low budget movie with low budget actors. Some are brilliant, some are not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_movie

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this is "[The Crawling Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trollenberg_Terror)," aka "The Trollenberg Terror".  Doesn't anybody remember "The Crawling Eye?" The giant eyes used their lashes like tentacles and they came out of a thick fog. If I remember correctly the end of the movie was at an observatory where the protagonists were holed up and eventually learned that fire would destroy the crawling eyeballs.  I have since found out that there are trailers for this movie on Youtube.

Comment: IMDB makes no mention of a supermarket.  It is almost entirely on trains and in a hotel.

Comment: @Dave Johnson - maybe the original questioner is mixing up some different old movies--I know there was a scene of characters trapped in a market in "The Blob" for example, but no fog or tentacles in that one.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Sure, definitely possible, but the reference of The Mist (in which most of the story was in a supermarket) indicates it was more than a single scene.

Answer (score 3):

Oh no my friends, if you want fog shrouded monsters and a supermarket, then the answer must be

[The Slime People](http://www.bmoviecentral.com/bmc/reviews/98-the-slime-people-1962-76-minutes.html)

This 1963 turkey fits the time frame, offers plenty of thick fog, monsters  and a butcher shop/supermarket. No tentacles really but given the vague information in the original question he may be mis-remembering this element. It has also been a staple of Saturday Creature Feature showings.

Here is the MST3k version to help jog the original poster's memory.

[Slime People Video (MST3k)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbZFBgSOvBQ&feature=youtu.be&t=3874)

Answer (score -2):

I think it was called The Fog. But I'm not certain.

Comment: It would greatly help your answer to give some examples of how *The Fog* matches the description given, and perhaps link to a plot description.

Comment: The Fog (1980) and (2005) both deal with a fog - but there are no tentacled monsters or scenes in a supermaket.

Comment: I bet you confuse this with **The Mist** from 2007, which is also based on Stephen King's Book from 1980. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mist_(film)), [Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhCKXJNGzN8), [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0884328/)) Interesting enough, I immediately thought of that movie as well.

Comment: "Hartford". It's the only word that the protagonist in _The Mist_ can make out from the static on his car radio. Am I the only one to notice that Hartford CT is the "insurance capital" of the Northeast if not the U.S.? Sly commentary by Stephen King on our vain hope to buy "security" through ammassing insurance policies.

Comment: In the Fog(1980) from John Carpenter the people are hiding in a church. The other movie is called the "The Mist" (2007) the people are hiding in a supermarket